# Save a value stretching over several rows while reading a file by row

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im writing a small python script that reads parameters and their values off of a few .c files in a dir. The parameters usually have this format:

```
uint8 param1 = 1;
sint8 param2 = 2;
```

However, sometimes they can look like this:

```
param3 = {
1, 2, 3,
4, 5, 6
};
```

or even:

```
param4 = {
1, 2, 3,
{
4, 5, 6
},
};
```

as you suspect in the situation involving `param3 and param4` the line will be `param3 = {` and same for `param4` and as such doesn't contain any actual values. I thought I would solve it before the value grabbing method is called by searching for "{" in a line, if it is found, then find it's ending somehow by finding the very next iteration of ";" in lines below the line containing "{" and inbetween any newlines, tabs and whitespaces should be removed. 
This is the output I wish the method would show when run correctly.

```
param3 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
param4 = {1,2,3,{4,5,6},};
```

This is the layout I am using, `formatFile(line)` being the very method I need help with.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PATH_DST_SOURCE):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.c'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as this:
                for line in this:
                    formatFile(line)
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this and would love some help or even a nudge in the correct direction. And of course if there is a better way of addressing my issue, then those are also welcome!

Comment: well using `for line in this` wouldn't work because the structure you are looking at spans over multiple lines no?

Comment: So you just need to filter out all variable definitions of the form `[type] name = (number|"{"list of numbers"}")` or what else are you parsing the files for?

Comment: Will `;` always end the line, or could another statement start in the same line?

Comment: As Stefano's answer explains, this is tricky to do properly, especially if the `.c` files may contain comments, or the parameters can contain strings. But if you can **guarantee** that the `.c` files don't have comments or strings that contain `';'` you may be able to use a simple approach.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a simple approach (admittedly not reading row by row):

```
with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as this:
    content = this.read().replace('\n', '')  # whole file in one line
    content = content.replace(';', ';\n')    # add linebreak after each ';'
    lines = content.split('\n')  # now each line contains one parameter assignment
```

Comment: I am not sure that the OP even knows he can read the entire file at once. So it should be suggested.

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution for me and my limited knowledge about python. 
The reason I read by line is because it gets easier for me when the script is gonna execute other commands. I have no problem with reading the entire file, maybe I should've mentioned that - its my fault - I hadn't thought about it. I'll get back and properly flag it, thanks!

Comment: Note that this could fail if a `;` is inside a string or a comment; also, I think this can be simplifed by splitting by `;` directly instead of replacing with `\n` first, or not?

Answer (score 1):

**Proposing a completely different solution... just give this a small thought....**

parsing C files as string is normally a tedious work which is very error prone. You can try using some regular expression but quite often you will find yourself saying:

- oh... i never thought they could put a space there...
- what if they put a comment in here...
- what if someone adds useless brackets...

if you want to build something robust do not parse the code yourself... try to find something that does this for you. 
What I would try doing for instance is a Swig interface to your C file and then access directly the variable.

General doc: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html

Accessing global variale: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn16

If you can use this solution the only thing you have to do is to write a few lines small interface file, give this as input to the Swig software and this will generate for you a python module which wraps up your C file.

**EDIT:**

This is simply what you could do in your case:

1.Install Swig
2.Create a file myInterface.i as follow:

```
/* File: myInterface.i */

%include "stdint.i"
%{
#include "file.h"
%}
extern uint8 param1;
extern uint8 param2;
```

3. run command `swig -python myInterface.i` this will generate for you a python wrapper for your header file.
4. import this file in your Python script and directly access the variables from your header file.

I do not remeber what to do for Array but they are for sure also accessible!

Comment: That's exactly how i was thinking. It made my script a bit complex, but I learned a lot of things about python by it. However, this seems too complex for me, I began coding in python about 3 weeks back, and the things I did were pretty easy to code. I will remember this comment for future as I'm sure I will find valuable info through it, thanks!

Comment: well.... i think that this si actually easier that what you are doing. I can add for you info some extra to my description. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this: Have a list of statements and a string holding the current statement; add to the current statement, until it ends in `;`, then add it to the list of statements.

```
with open("file.c") as f:
    statements = []
    cur = ""
    for line in f:
        cur += line.strip()
        if cur.endswith(";"):
            statements.append(cur)
            cur = ""
```

Of course, this is assuming that each statement-ending `;` is actually at the end of the line, and not, e.g. followed by a line comment, or (part of) another statement. If you also want to tackle those cases, things get much more complicated (statement-like code inside line- or block-comments, or in string, etc.) and you should probably look for some existing parser library.

Comment: All statements end with ; and nothing follows. This seems also simple enough for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re
pattern = r'((?P<type>\w+)\s+)?(?P<name>\w+)\s*=\s*(?P<value>.+?);'

with open("example.c") as cfile:
    assignments = []
    for m in re.finditer(pattern, cfile, re.DOTALL):
        dic = m.groupdict()
        dic["value"] = dic["value"].replace("\n", " ")
        assignments.append(dic)

    print assignments
```

From this code you get a list of dictionaries with the keys `"type"` (data type of the assigned variable), `"name"` (assigned variable name) and `"value"` (whatever is getting assigned). Each dictionary represents one assignment.

The output would be this (line-breaks added manually for clarity):

```
[{'type': 'uint8', 'name': 'param1', 'value': '1'}, 
 {'type': 'sint8', 'name': 'param2', 'value': '2'}, 
 {'type': None, 'name': 'param3', 'value': '{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }'}, 
 {'type': None, 'name': 'param4', 'value': '{ 1, 2, 3, { 4, 5, 6 }, }'}]
```

... for this input file:

```
uint8 param1 = 1;
sint8 param2 = 2;

param3 = {
1, 2, 3,
4, 5, 6
};

param4 = {
1, 2, 3,
{
4, 5, 6
},
};
```

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, this fails if there can be strings or comments containing ";" characters.